# SSH experiment, Sharing .ssh folder in NFS to do passwordless SSH

Tags: ssh

I have two machines with same username (medya), I have mounted their ~/.ssh folder though a network file storage (nfs). so all the files in their ~/.ssh folder are same (and synced).

I did

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

I was expecting to be able to ssh to other machine without a password, but I got this error:

```
bash-4.1$ ssh 10.16.4.114
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

note that I know this is possible because I had done this before...any clue what I am doing wrong this time?

Answer (score -2):

1. chmod g-w /home/medya
2. chmod 700 /home/medya/.ssh
3. chmod 600 /home/medya/.ssh/authorized_keys
4. have your private key ready

Comment: I did all those and still says, Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: are you trying to use ssh on the same machine you applied the changes to the folders? (it seems to be the case, looking into your comment before you edited it)

Comment: I have two machines, but their .ssh folder are same (the folder is over network) no I try to ssh from .113 to .114 (their last part of ip)

Comment: Assuming your pub file was successfully added to authorized_keys files and you have your private key file availabe. Please try the -i option using your private key file:
e.g. : ssh -i /home/medya/.ssh/id_dsa medya@x.x.x.114 ...

Comment: same error : 
bash-4.1$ ssh -i id_rsa medya@10.16.4.114
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: btw I set the LogLevel to Deubg in sshd_config and restarted it, but still I don't get any more details of error ...same error.

Comment: you can try the verbose -v option too and see what it is using or trying to use.

Comment: debug3: Not a RSA1 key file id_rsa.

You should fix that or change the link to the correct folder/file. Nevertheless ensure that the folder permissions are set correctly on both nodes, your host you want to connect from and the remote host.
This still seems not to be correct.

Comment: the log compalined about key not being in RSA1 format I regenerated the key using ssh-keygen -t rsa , now it complains about something else it says ```debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 ``` full log here https://gist.github.com/medyagh/a7353b3e78979298a121

Comment: Last ideas: check SELinux settings if appropriate for your machines. Hard fix:"restorecon -R ~/.ssh" and check the log files on server side /var/log/secure or auth.log maybe. Recreate a clean authorized_keys file with touch and add your new pub key.

Comment: I did all those, and /var/secure log I see something this ```Mar 11 13:46:03 ip-10-16-4-113 sshd[12769]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/tools/appsw/oracle/orainst/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied``` the permission for authorized keys is 600, I tried to increase to 644 test it same

Comment: Interesting folder structure. You shouldn't change the permissions, the permissions should be as descibed here and elsewhere. Is this really the file you configured in ssh config files and where you added the public key? Is your user owner of this file? Is this file accessible while the user is not logged in (maybe the filesystem is encrypted on user level or something similar, usual problem with non-server environments like Ubuntu Desktop, where encryption is suggested to the user during installation)